# It is impossible to deduce a custom product options

Tags: product, catalog, custom-options

i have product in catalog list:

[image]

i have custom options in details page:

[image]

how i can output custom option in catalog page:

[image]

i need is same options display in catalog page, options will be is same how and in product list

Thanks for the help!

Comment: there are different options but may you want to just easy use one of the extensions available like that: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/23130/s/product-custom-options/

Comment: thanks, but all my custom options in dropdown, if i use radiobutton, then not working if options radibutton is required